# Is there a relationship between vitamin D levels and cholesterol?

Tags: micronutrients, cholesterol, vitamin-d, hdl, ldl

I've been trying to read up on high cholesterol and there is *a lot* of information out there about it. In addition to "don't eat fatty foods" and "exercise more," there are some sources that mention vitamin D as a possible contributor to improving cholesterol levels.

> The test group received a daily dose of 1,000 mg of elemental calcium
> along with 400 IUs of vitamin D3....
>
> Blood levels of vitamin D, fasting plasma triglycerides, HDL, and LDL
> cholesterol levels were assessed at the beginning and end of the
> trial. After two years, women who received the vitamin D and calcium
> supplements had a 38 percent increased mean vitamin D level compared
> to the placebo group.
>
> They also had a 4.46-mg/dL mean decrease in LDL. Furthermore, higher
> vitamin D concentrations were associated with higher HDL combined with
> lower LDL and triglyceride levels.

### Edit:

The quote was originally from [Mercola](http://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2014/04/14/vitamin-d-cholesterol-levels.aspx), but, the article seems no longer to exist. However, the originating study seems to be Schnatz, et al. ([2014](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5234488/))

It looks like there is a correlation, but I'm curious how that works.

### References

Schnatz, P. F., Jiang, X., Vila-Wright, S., Aragaki, A. K., Nudy, M., O'Sullivan, D. M., Jackson, R., LeBlanc, E., Robinson, J. G., Shikany, J. M., Womack, C. R., Martin, L. W., Neuhouser, M. L., Vitolins, M. Z., Song, Y., Kritchevsky, S., & Manson, J. E. (2014). Calcium/vitamin D supplementation, serum 25-hydroxyvitamin D concentrations, and cholesterol profiles in the Women's Health Initiative calcium/vitamin D randomized trial. *Menopause, 21*(8), 823–833. https://doi.org/10.1097/GME.0000000000000188

Answer (score 6):

According to a couple of systematic reviews of studies, there is **insufficient evidence** about the lowering effect of vitamin D on blood cholesterol levels.

1. Vitamin D, Evidence [Mayo Clinic (data from Natural Standard Research Collaboration)](http://www.mayoclinic.org/drugs-supplements/vitamin-d/evidence/hrb-20060400)

> Many studies have looked at the effects of vitamin D alone or in
>   combination with other agents for high cholesterol, but **results are
>   inconsistent.** Some negative effects have been reported.

2. Zitterman A et al, 2011, The role of vitamin D in dyslipidemia and cardiovascular disease [a systematic review]  ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21418036))

> The vast majority of intervention studies **did not show an effect** of
>   vitamin D on serum cholesterol levels.